# Negation of the Definition of Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, propositional-calculus

$\textbf{Definition}.$

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n \in V$. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ be scalars. Let $\textbf{0}$ be the zero element of $V$.

$\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n$ are said to be linearly independent if $$\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0$$

Firstly, is this a valid definition of linear independence?

Secondly, how do I find the negation of this definition of linear independence? I would expect to get something like there exist scalars $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, not all zero, such that $\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0}$, but I am not sure how I would arrive at something like this.

Comment: You are right about the negation.

Comment: @xbh Yes, I suspected so, but I would like to know how to (i.e go through some explicit steps) to negate the definition to arrive at something equivalent to what I wrote at the end.

Comment: Reverse the quantifiers, i.e. "for all" to "exist one", "exist one" to "for all". Also take the negation of the statement.

Comment: Example. The definition of linear independence could be rewritten as "if $\sum \alpha_j \boldsymbol v_j = \mathbf 0, $then all $\alpha_j = 0$" [the other direction holds always under the context of vector space]. Now take the negation of the conclusion above: "all" becomes "some", "$\alpha_j = 0$" becomes "$\alpha_j \neq 0$". Combine them together yields "some $\alpha_j $can be nonzero despite that equation holds".

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for pointing out. I have noticed these flaws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of linear dependence is valid, although we usually only write $\implies$ since the left-hand arrow is trivial. Of course, to say we can deduce all $\alpha_i$ is equivalent to saying there does *not* exist any other choice of the $\alpha_i$ that works. Therefore, the negation is as expected to say that one *does*.

Comment: I guess this is pretty obvious, thank you. I was wishing to see for myself that what you have said follows from explicit negation of the definition using predicate calculus, but I have now convinced myself of this by writing it out on paper.